# Memory use of storing the same list twice, sorted on different criteria?

Tags: c#, list

This is a theoretical example but hopefully it highlights my question:

Let's say I have a master list of `Item` objects, and an `Item` has two properties, say `Weight` and `Value`.

The program will very frequently be required to sort by `Weight` and get the lightest `Item` whilst elsewhere it is being sorted by `Value` and getting the most expensive `Item`.

The master list has the potential to be very large, so it would be lots of unnessary work to keep sorting the master list over and over. To save time is it possible to store the sorted result as its own list? Will these other lists simply store pointers to the real objects and not just store them again?

Comment: Unrelated - but you might also consider keeping the data in a *database*, with some combination of clustered and non-clustered indexing, and just query *that*. Databases are very good at that...

Comment: Why do you need to sort the list if you just want the lightest or most expensive item?

Comment: @adrianm What alternatives are there? I can only think of using something like LINQ but even then the performance is slow on large lists, compared to just taking the 0 index on a sorted list. As the list is largely unchanging, but it is polled often, I thought it would be better this way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This depends on whether `Item` is a `struct` or a `class`. If it is a `class` (as would be the sensible default), then ***both*** lists only contain references to the objects - there will be no duplication of all the `Weight` / `Value` values. If it is a `struct`, then all the values *will* be duplicated, as each will have a separate backing vector, and the actual structs will be in the vector. Side note: if the values are *strings*, then note that strings are *also* reference types, so the string *contents* won't be duplicated (unless they were created separately, without any pseudo-interning, etc).

Comment: That's what I hoped to hear and yes, in the actual code I'm asking this about they are `class`es.

Answer (score 3):

> Will these other lists simply store <del>pointers</del> references to the real objects and not just store them again?

As long as `Item` is a class and not a struct: yes.

Answer (score 0):

as we can read [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/490f96s2.aspx) classes are reference types, which means they won't be copied to the new list

you can indeed keep two lists and keep them sorted one by `price` and the other by `Weight` and thus make life easier for you